# asp.net 5 404 handling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

I have read tons of articles on handling 404 errors with the new ASP.NET 5 stuff, but I'm still unsure how to set up the following scenario:

1. Let Web API controllers return 404 errors, perhaps with a custom message in the response body like "the specified spell id could not be found".
2. All other 404 errors keep the current url, return a 404 status code, and display the contents of either an MVC error view or a static html file (don't care which).
3. Allow IIS to handle static files rather than ASP.NET (this condition complicates things because it means we can't put a catch-all route or a catch-all middleware to keep all requests from falling through to IIS).

Here's the example that is not working:

In Startup.cs Configure method:

```
app.UseErrorHandler("/error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
app.UseMvc(...);
```

In web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/error/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And a very basic test controller:

```
[Route("api/blah")]
public class BlahController : Controller
{
    // GET: spell/12345
    [HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Spell(int id)
    {
        if (id != 12345)
            return new HttpNotFoundObjectResult(new { Message = "not there bro" });

        return new ObjectResult(new SpellJson
        {
            Id = id,
            Name = "test"
        });
    }
}
```

I am running in IIS Express.

**Here's what happens:**
1. If I browse to a non-existent url like http://localhost:49858/asdf, I see the html generated by my /error/404 view, great!

2. If I call /api/blah/12345 from javascript, I get my JSON data, great!
3. If I call /api/blah/999 from javascript, I get a 404 error but the response body is the html generated by /error/404 rather than the JSON { Message: "not there bro" }, bad!

Which part up there is making my controller that explicitly returns a HttpNotFoundObjectResult instead execute the error page?  How do I set things up to allow Web API controller methods to return 404 without going to the error page, but catch all other 404 errors with the error page?